# Active Directory - UNIX Attributes of user using C#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, unix, active-directory

I'm trying to make use of UNIX attributes in Active Directory while creating users using C#. How can I fill and make sure that UNIX attributes are correct?

- What attributes to set?
- How to get correct UID? (conflicts, Windows automatic UID generation and so on...)
- What is **unixUserPassword** attribute - why is it always set to 'ABCD!efgh....something' on every user added to unix using UNIX Attributes?

Comment: Do you have NIS service installed ?

Comment: @JPBlanc NIS? I've only installed Active Directory Domain Services and Unix Integration feature. I don't know if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my contribution : places that can help you :

[General information about SFU](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/)

[Manually populating information in Unix attribute](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2010/05/26/manually-populating-information-in-unix-attribute-tab.aspx)

[A simple script to manage UNIX related attributes in Windows 2003 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2010/01/05/a-simple-script-to-manage-unix-related-attributes-in-windows-2003-r2.aspx)

[Identity Management for UNIX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782782%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

[Windows Security and Directory Services for UNIX Guide v1.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496504.aspx)